# How to easily detect click inside of rectangle/image?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

When I draw an image, I know I could find out whether the user clicks on it by comparing X,Y of mouse with position and size of that image.
However is there a quicker way? I know for two rectangles there is an intersect methods.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, the same thing has to happen. The point coordinates need to be tested against the rectangle coordinates. But if you already have Rectangle r and Point p, you can do `if (r.Contains(p))`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible (as I'm a bit unclear on what you are trying to accomplish), but maybe you can put a button behind the area you want to make clickable and assign an image to that button.